# Error no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Person' and 'Person*')

Tags: c++, structure

```
In function 'int main()':
41  14      [Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Person' and 'Person*')
41  14      [Note] candidate is:
8   8       [Note] Person& Person::operator=(const Person&)
8   8       [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Person*' to 'const Person&'
28          recipe for target 'main112.o' failed
```

Homework:

Write a program for processing passenger information. Information includes:
1) Full name of the passenger.
2) Flight number.
3) Luggage weight
The program should allow the user to:
1) Read data from the keyboard and display it.
2) Calculate the number of passengers with the weight of baggage which is more than 10 kg

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Person
{
    string name;
    string race;
    int weight;

    void write();
    void show();
    void check();
};

void Person::show()
{
    cout<<"ÔÈÎ: "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Íîìåð ðåéñà: "<<race<<endl;
    cout<<"Âåñ áàãàæà: "<<weight<<endl;
}

void Person::write()
{
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå ÔÈÎ: ";
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå íîìåð ðåéñà: ";
    getline(cin,race);
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå âåñ áàãàæà: ";
    cin>>weight;
}

int main()
{
    Person* persons=new Person[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        persons[i] = new Person();
        persons[i].write();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        persons[i].show();
    }
    cout<<"Ñ áàãàæîì áîëüøå 10 êã: ";//<<counter<<" ÷åëîâåê"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now I've got new problem: it doesnt give opportunity to fill "name" after first structure element 
Thats console: 
name: xzx race: 12312 weight: 32 name: race: 32 weight: 54654 name: race etc 
Why it doesnt ask me to input name?

Answer (score 2):

When you call this line:

```
Person* persons = new Person[4];
```

Then this already makes four persons. You don't need the following line:

```
persons[i] = new Person();
```

Just remove this line. It returns a `Person*` which can't be assigned to `persons[i]`, which refers to an actual `Person` (and not a pointer). But since you already made the four Persons in the first line, you don't need this line at all.

You should, however, delete the persons when you're done:

```
delete[] persons;
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but now ive got new problem: it doesnt give opportunity to fill "name" after first structure element

Thats console:
name: xzx 
race: 12312
weight: 32

name: race: 32
weight: 54654

name: race etc

Why it doesnt ask me to input name?

Comment: I think it's leaving a newline in the buffer after getting the weight, so the `getline` for the next line will just get that newline and call it a day. You could try adding `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), cin.widen('\n'));` after the `cin >> weight;` to ensure that the newline is consumed.